# send parameter to Java Server Pages (JSP) using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to send different parameters to JSP. Is it possible to send multiple parameter to JSP in jQuery? Because jQuery is client side and JSP is server side.

Update me!

Answer (score 2):

You can make an ajax request passing parameters

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "userNameCheck.jsp",
  data: { username: "John"}
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( msg );
  //do other processing
});
```

**See**

- [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case: you want to open some page with javascript (jQuery). In this case you can send parameters in request to page:

```
document.location.href = "http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.jsp?paramName=" + paramValue;
```

If you need to send data without page reloading use ajax as Jigar say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "yoursite.com",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {param1: value1 , param2: "value2", param3: "value3"},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: Succeess,
                    error: Failed
                });
```