# Communicating between JavaScript and Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jquery

In my JSP page I have `DIV`.

```
<div id="100">
ALI
</div>
```

When I click on this `DIV`...

```
$("#100").click(function(){

});
```

...I need to send the value of the `id 100`, to a servlet, so that the servlet makes some database java codes, and returns for example, either 1 or 0. How can I do that? and is this the proper way?

Comment: I recommend you read about JQuery's AJAX implementation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ajax, you should call your server using a URL similar to this:

```
http://localhot:8080/youAppContext/yourServer?id=100
```

Then, in the servler side, you should retrieve the value that will be in the request with the name "id"

There are out there many tool as jQuery that can help you to do the Ajax petition.

**Edited**

Well, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax2) you can find a very simple Ajax example using jQuery. In the example, instead call a file (test1.txt) you should invoke a URL (as I described above). Of course, you will need to write some JS code to build your URL (where id be a variable). Once task is done in servlet side, you can return whatever, for example: "done" and display or not this information the HTML as it is done in the example.

Take a look to this [Web](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp), there are many links that can help you.

Comment: I know that I should use Ajax but can you give me a small tiny example ? :(

Comment: 1 more question, in the URL you wrote, you wrote "youServer", this page is a JSP page or a servlet? I am using NetBeans, how to get the URL of a servlet?

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial: http://www.servlets.com/jservlet2/examples/ch02/index.html servlet name or servlet alias is defined in the web.xml file through the servlet mapping. Inthe exmaple you can see how you can define an alias in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

get the value using

```
var value = $("#100").html();
```

and pass it to [servlet using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752496/send-parameter-to-java-server-pages-jsp-using-jquery)

Comment: I know how to get it but not how to pass it using AJAX :(